# android webview jquery mobile pageshow not firing on navigating back

Tags: android, web-applications, jquery-mobile

A strange peculiar thing is happening in Android WebView.The page show is firing only once when the page is first loaded.Then if i navigate to another jquery mobile page and then navigate back.The page show is not invoked.
Desktop version of Firefox,Chrome,IE and IE9 on windows phone, all working fine ,all of them  calls the page show ,whenever the page is shown, except android Webview
Am I doing something wrong ?

I am using webview on Android 2.3 Emulator

```
$(document).off('pageshow', '#HomePage');
$(document).on('pageshow', '#HomePage', getMessage);
function getMessage(evt) {
alert("hi");
}
```

I have used webview.setWebChromeClient and it displays other alerts fine.

Comment: probably only an emulator problem? Did you test on an Android device?

Comment: No I did not test in an android device